# Alt+* has to be pressed twice in Mate 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate

After upgrading to Ubuntu Mate 18.04, I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or other <kbd>Alt</kbd>+something combos twice to get them work. Very annoying.

I walked through all thinkable options, and can't find where it can be changed to work as before.

I checked <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (to switch immediately between windows), and it also works only after two strokes.

In Keyboard Options, compose key = <kbd>Left Win</kbd>, switching to another layout = <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> (worked perfectly this way for last several years). No keys are assigned for 3rd or 5th levels.

I tested if setting and unsetting 3rd/5th levels would work. When they are set, it does, <kbd>Alt</kbd> works correctly.

[image]

But as soon as I unset these, <kbd>Alt</kbd> starts again needing 2 strokes.

What can I do?

Comment: I got the same problem since this morning. It always appears, a few minutes or an hour or so after a reboot, but sometimes it goes away after a while. Looks like a bug.

Comment: A. When I am in greek keyboard, I need two alt-tabs to start switching windows, whereas when I'm in US keyboard, I need a single one. Reproducible now.

Comment: Same here. With GB keyboard Alt+<any key> works fine, when switching to italian keyboard I need to press it twice.

Comment: Even when using Alt+mouse to move or resize windows I have to: press and keep Alt, press tab, click-and-drag mouse, release Alt, or it won't work. And this one happens with both GB and IT keyboard.